# Swashbuckle/Swagger on .NET Core 2.1 has stopped working since upgrade

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a .NET Core 2.0 application, using Swashbuckle/Swagger to generate API documentation. When we were on 2.1.0-preview, Swagger was working fine. Then we did the big upgrade to 2.1.0 release and SDK 2.1.300. We didn't notice exactly when things broke, but now our Swagger docs won't load. Here's what we see:
[image: Failed to load API definition Errors Fetch error undefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json]

Project has a reference to `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` version 2.5.0. The relevant code in `Startup.cs` is below. In `ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(swaggerOptions =>
{
    // Register a swagger doc
    swaggerOptions.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
    {
        // Optional descriptive info that will be included in the Swagger output
        Contact = new Contact
        {
            Name = "LightSail",
            Url = "https://myurl.com/"
        },
        Description = "A description of the API can go here",
        Title = "My API",
        Version = "v1"
    });

    // Xml file to get comment information from
    swaggerOptions.IncludeXmlComments("App_Data/Api.xml");
});
```

And in `Configure()`:

```
app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(swaggerUiOptions => swaggerUiOptions.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API v1"));
```

I found lots of other similar questions, one of which suggested that there might be duplicate endpoints; I tried adding a call to `.ResolveConflictingEndpoints()` but that made no difference. I have searched through my project folders and there is no file called `swagger.json`, so I'm guessing that's the problem.

Any ideas why this is not working, or how to fix?

Comment: I have it working in 2.1 try   c.SwaggerEndpoint("./v1/swagger.json", "Api v1");

Comment: @KirstenGreed Didn't help, but thanks anyway

Comment: Do you have a minimal example reproducing your issue?

Comment: @HelderSepu I wish... :-/

Comment: Can you create one, this is impossible to troubleshoot with the given info...

Comment: are you using `[ApiController]`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is usually indicative of controllers/actions that Swashbuckle doesn't support for one reason or another.

It's expected that you don't have a swagger.json file in your project. Swashbuckle creates and serves that dynamically using ASP.NET Core's ApiExplorer APIs. What's probably happening here is that Swashbuckle is unable to generate Swagger.json and, therefore, the UI is failing to display.

As HelderSepu said, it's hard to know exactly what caused the failure, so the best way to debug is probably just to remove half your controllers (just move the files to a temporary location) and check whether the issues persists. Then you'll know which half of your controllers contains the troublesome action. You can 'binary search' removing controllers (and then actions) until you figure out which action method is causing Swashbuckle to not be able to generate Swagger.json. Once you know that, it should be obvious whether this is some issue in your code or an issue that should be filed in the [Swashbuckle repo](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore).

For example, Swashbuckle appears to not support open generics, so having a response type attribute like `[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<>))]` could cause this sort of behavior. It could also be an issue with ambiguous routes or something like that tripping Swashbuckle up. Once you've narrowed down the cause of failure to something more specific like that, it can either be fixed or filed, as appropriate.

Comment: The binary search idea helped me find the problematic endpoint, thanks!

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. I only have one very lightweight controller, with a small series of Get actions. I can navigate to the /swagger/v1/swagger.json, and see that the file is correct. I can copy it and paste it in the Swagger Editor, and that works fine too.
However, when I try to go to the /swagger url, I'm pushed to the /swagger/index.html page and get the **Fetch Error** described above.

Comment: This also occurs in asp.net core 3.0, here we do not have `ResponseType` anymore but got replaced by `ProducesResponseType` also the new 'standard' response object seems to be `IActionResult` which seems to result into swagger errors.

Comment: Binary search was a great idea and showed me the problem much quicker than staring at code and configs - I just looked to see controllers with recent commits and remmed all the code of them until I narrowed down the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Today I found out that I could just go to the json url in the browser and get some error information
for example

myapiurl/api/vi/swagger.json

Comment: Thank you! This helped me identify what was causing my error.

Comment: This is not working for me. If my Swagger page has a custom url at `https://example.com/myswaggerpage`, what is the URL from which I can get the error information?

Comment: This was not working for me either. My json wouldn't build. The thing that saved me was to check Output in Visual Studio after running the WebAPI.
Seriously, all swagger errors are logged there!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this error by explicitly adding the http verb attribute to my asp.net core 2.x controller method.  The convention of prefixing the method name with the http verb is not enough for Swashbuckle apparently.

`[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddNewData([FromBody] MyType myType) { … }`

Comment: This fixed it in my case.

Comment: This fixed in my case too, I simply added     [HttpGet] to my API
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetAll()

Answer (score 3):

In my case I can reproduce your error by omitting "." from the end point as you have done.
[image]

I don't get the error if I include "." at the start of the path.
Here is more of my code in case it is relevant.

In ConfigureServices I have

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.OperationFilter<AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();

        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
        {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = "My API",
            Description = "ASP.NET Core Web API",
            TermsOfService = "None",
            Contact = new Contact
            {
                Name = "my name",
                Email = "me@myemail.com"
            }
        });
    });
```

In configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();


    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent());

    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.RouteTemplate =
            "api-docs/{documentName}/swagger.json";
    });
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        //Include virtual directory if site is configured so
        c.RoutePrefix = "api-docs";
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("./v1/swagger.json", "Api v1");
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "default",
            "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

Also there is

```
public class AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var filterPipeline = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors;
            var isAuthorized = filterPipeline.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Filter).Any(filter => filter is AuthorizeFilter);
            var allowAnonymous = filterPipeline.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Filter).Any(filter => filter is IAllowAnonymousFilter);

            if (isAuthorized && !allowAnonymous)
            {
                if (operation.Parameters == null)
                    operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>();

                operation.Parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter
                {
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = "header",
                    Description = "access token",
                    Required = true,
                    Type = "string"
                });
            }
        }
```

My dependencies are

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (2.1.0)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (2.5.0)
Microsoft.NETCore.App (2.1.0)
```

Comment: In my case I was facing the problem only when publishing the web apis to IIS. When launching the project from VS2017 no issue was found. MJRousos answer was useless for me, while yours is working. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Personally I was a bit quick and forgot to add this line to the method ConfigureServices in Startup.cs.

`services.AddSwaggerDocument();`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I missed the 'HttpAttribute':

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ClientesListDto>> GetAll()
{
     return await _service.GetAllAsync();
}
```

Then I put it and swagger likes it:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<ClientesListDto>> GetAll()
{
     return await _service.GetAllAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had this:

```
    [HttpGet("CleanUpSnoozedLeads")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> CleanUpSnoozedLeads()


    [HttpGet("CleanUpSnoozedLeads")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> DoSomethingElse()
```

Notice the HttpGet() had the same name. That causes the undefined error as well.

Answer (score 0):

A very common case is ambiguity. Just use the same signature for two PUT or POST operations for example and you will get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Others answers did not worked for me.

I was able to fix and understand my issue when I tried to go to the swagger.json URL location:

```
https://localhost:XXXXX/swagger/v1/swagger.json
```

The page will show the error and reason why it is not found.

In my case, I saw that there was a misconfigured XML definition of one of my methods based on the error it returned:

```
NotSupportedException: HTTP method "GET" & path "api/Values/{id}" overloaded by actions - ...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i just forgot to add the HttpPostAttribute annotation to the method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a conflict in the schemaId. Apparently every class in the swagger JSON must have a unique schemaId. If you have two classes in different namespaces with the same name this will not work. We have to configure "UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds" in the startup class.
Add "options.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);" in "services.AddSwaggerGen"
I found the trace by enabling Output window in VS, selecting the main project from Show output from dropdown list then visit http://{yourapiendpoint}/swagger/v1/swagger.json

Answer (score 0):

If your api have  same two or more  `[HttpGet]` its not working swagger.
You should be specify   [HttpGet]   , `[HttpGet ("{id}")]`
simple solution